# How to write testmethods for methods without parameters?

Tags: c#, tdd

I'm trying to understand TDD but all the examples I've seen, shows methods like add(), substract() etc. Which I understand how to test through unittest. But how to test a method without parameters?

How would you, for example, write a testmethod for this method?

```
    public List<string> testmethod()
    {
        List<string> ret = new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constring))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            SqlDataReader reader;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from users";

            conn.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ret.Add(reader["name"].ToString());
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

I mean, what do you have to test against?

Comment: test if it returns a list with strings?

Comment: Typically you would inject a IDbConnection and then mock that to make sure this method interacted with it properly.  Or you would have code to setup the DB and test that this returned the correct data, but that's integration testing, not unit testing.

Comment: As for any method (regardless of the fact that it takes parameters or return something), the idea is to make sure the method does what it's supposed to do. In your case, make sure it reads users name from the db.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically you wouldn't *unit test* that method.  Since the code is coupled to the database it would be an *integration* test.  (If you want to test logic separately from data access then you'd break this into two components, one with the logic and one with the data access.)

Aside from that little nitpick though, the pattern is the same.  Any repeatable automated test should have three steps:

1. Arrange
2. Act
3. Assert

Assuming that the "Act" step is simply this:

```
var result = testmethod();
```

What, then, would be the "Assert" step?  How can you know that this method did what it's supposed to do?  It returns a result, so I imagine you'd examine that result to see if it's what you expect it to be given certain known conditions.

What are those conditions?  That's the "Arrange" step.  The idea is that you set up a known scenario where you expect a known result.  Then you execute the code.  Then you check if the result is what you expect.

For example, instead of the example of `Add(1, 1)` which you already know how to test, consider this object:

```
public class Adder
{
    public int Augend { get; set; }
    public int Addend { get; set; }

    public int Add()
    {
        return Augend + Addend;
    }
}
```

(It's a silly object I know, but bear with me.)

How would you test that method by itself?  By first setting up the environment:

```
// Arrange
var adder = new Adder();
adder.Augend = 1;
adder.Addend = 1;

// Act
var result = adder.Add();

// Assert
Assert.AreEqual(2, result);
```

In your case that "Arrange" step might get pretty involved, since there's direct access to a database.  But the concept is the same.  The test first creates a known state of the system, then performs an action, then examines the new state of the system.  (If the creation of the state and the examination of the state, as well as the side-effects left afterward, are a bit cumbersome then that's a good indication that there's too much coupling in the code and you'd want to break things apart a bit.)

Answer (score 5):

Your method actually does multiple things, which are:

1. Execute a query
2. Convert the query-results to a list of strings.

Unfortunately one of these things are not really suitable for unit testing (the execution of the query), but the other thing is. So ideally you should split up your method, and then you can test the conversion logic.